# Form character*(*) for character variable generation

Tags: fortran

I have a third party script for a subroutine that I need to work with. This subroutine is as follows

```
  Subroutine COpen(io, Name )
      Character*(*) Name
      Character*1023 NameIn, NameOut
      NameIn = Trim(Name)//' '
      Call Get_OrMakeFileName( NameIn, NameOut )
      Open(io,file=NameOut,access="APPEND")
  End
```

I don't understand the `Character*(*) name` syntax. Isn't the typical way to declare string variables simply. `character ::  name*4` with the `*4` part designating the number of characters? Can anyone please explain the purpose of this alternate syntax? What kind of object does it generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: `character*(*)` declares a character variable of assumed length.

There are a number of ways of declaring the length of a character variable.  One, as seen in the question's code, is

```
character*1023  ...
```

where a literal constant follows the `*`.  Equivalent to that is

```
character([len=]1023) ...
```

(`len=` being optional).  In this case the length needn't be a literal constant.

These two forms declare a variable of a particular length.  There are two other forms of a length for a character variable:

- assumed length - `character([len=]*) ...` ;
- deferred length - `character([len=]:) ...`.

Like with `character*1023` the assumed and deferred length declarations may be written in this style:

```
character*(*) ...      ! Assumed length
character*(:) ...      ! Deferred length
character*(1023) ...   ! For completeness
```

Well, what does "assumed length" mean?

For a dummy argument such as `Name` it's length is taken from the length of the actual argument of the procedure.  With `character :: Name*4` the argument is of length 4, regardless of the length of the argument to the subroutine (as long as it's of length at least 4).  When the dummy is of assumed length it is of length 12 if the argument is of length 12, and so on.

---

Although not in the question, a character named constant may also assume its length from the defining expression:

```
character*(*), parameter :: label='This long'
```

Deferred length is left to other questions.

Comment: thanks. Do you mind checking my follow up question as well? I have simplified the problem a little bit.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787131/fortran-assumed-string-length-input-into-function