# Assumed string length input into a Fortran function

Tags: fortran, fortran90, string-concatenation

I am writing the following simple routine:

```
program scratch
    character*4 :: word
    word = 'hell'
    print *, concat(word)
end program scratch

function concat(x)
    character*(*) x
    concat = x // 'plus stuff'
end function concat
```

The program should be taking the string 'hell' and concatenating to it the string 'plus stuff'. I would like the function to be able to take in any length string (I am planning to use the word 'heaven' as well) and concatenate to it the string 'plus stuff'.

Currently, when I run this on Visual Studio 2012 I get the following error:

> Error 1    error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary
>   expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two
>   operands. D:\aboufira\Desktop\TEMP\Visual
>   Studio\test\logicalfunction\scratch.f90   9

This error is for the following line:

```
concat = x // 'plus stuff'
```

It is not apparent to me why the two operands are not compatible. I have set them both to be strings. Why will they not concatenate?

Comment: You haven't declared the type of the function `concat` and Fortran has gone right ahead and used good old *implicit typing* to determine that it is a `real` function whereas you have tried to assign a string to its return variable.  Any reasonable Fortran reference, and a host of SO qs and as, will explain the mechanics of implicit typing and that it is evil.  Beyond that you've not ensured the `program` has access to the interface of the function, so the program also thinks that `concat` is a real-valued thing. Do more research into the use of `contains` and of `module` in Fortran.

Comment: **Always** use `implicit none`. It will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

High Performance Mark's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787131/assumed-string-length-input-into-a-fortran-function#comment72688733_42787131) tells you about why the compiler complains: implicit typing.

The result of the function `concat` is implicitly typed because you haven't declared its type otherwise.  Although `x // 'plus stuff'` is the correct way to concatenate character variables, you're attempting to assign that new character object to a (implictly) real function result.

Which leads to the question: "just how do I declare the function result to be a character?".  Answer: much as you would any other character variable:

```
character(len=length) concat
```

[note that I use `character(len=...)` rather than `character*...`.  I'll come on to exactly why later, but I'll also point out that the form `character*4` is obsolete according to current Fortran, and may eventually be deleted entirely.]

The tricky part is: what is the length it should be declared as?

When declaring the length of a character function result which we don't know ahead of time there are two<sup>1</sup> approaches:

- an automatic character object;
- a deferred length character object.

In the case of this function, we know that the length of the result is 10 longer than the input.  We can declare

```
character(len=LEN(x)+10) concat
```

To do this we cannot use the form `character*(LEN(x)+10)`.

In a more general case, deferred length:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: concat  ! Deferred length, will be defined on allocation
```

where later

```
concat = x//'plus stuff'  ! Using automatic allocation on intrinsic assignment
```

Using these forms adds the requirement that the function `concat` has an explicit interface in the main program.  You'll find much about that in other questions and resources.  Providing an explicit interface will also remove the problem that, in the main program, `concat` also implicitly has a real result.

To stress:

```
program
  implicit none
  character(len=[something]) concat
  print *, concat('hell')
end program
```

will not work for `concat` having result of the "length unknown at compile time" forms.  Ideally the function will be an internal one, or one accessed from a module.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a third: assumed length function result.  Anyone who wants to know about this could read this [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42791082).  Everyone else should pretend this doesn't exist.  Just like the writers of the Fortran standard.

Comment: and here's the answer I didn't have the patience to write.