# What is an assumed length character function result, and why should it be avoided?

Tags: fortran

In response to a question [about character function results of non-constant length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42787131), an answer mentions "assumed length function result" but doesn't go into detail.

If I want to return a character result where the length depends on something else, that answer mentions automatic objects and deferred length as possible approaches:

```
function deferred_length(x)
  character(*), intent(in)  :: x
  character(:), allocatable :: deferred_length
  deferred_length = x//'!'
end function
```

or

```
function automatic(x)
  character(*), intent(in)  :: x
  character(LEN(x)+1)       :: automatic
  automatic = x//'!'
end function
```

What is an assumed length function result and how does it differ from the forms above?  Further, why is such mention relegated to a footnote?

Comment: Anyone who downvotes this, do you find the question unclear or not well researched? Self answered questions are not only allowed, but also encouraged if they are useful to others https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An assumed length character function looks like the following:

```
function assumed_len(x)
  character(*), intent(in)  :: x
  character(*)              :: assumed_len
  assumed_len = x//'!'
end function
```

Here the dummy argument `x` and the function result `assumed_len` are both assumed length characters.

Much like how `x` assumes its length from the actual argument when the function is referenced, the function result assumes its length from the function declaration *in the referencing place*.

With the above function, consider the program

```
implicit none
character(len=11) :: x='Hello world'
character(len=12) assumed_len

print *, assumed_len(x)

end
```

During the function's execution the function result has length 12 as declared in the main program.  Equally, if we wanted it to have length 5 we simply change the declaration in the main program to `character(len=5) assumed_len`.  In a different program unit the declaration could be something different and the function result would assume that length when referenced.

Well, that doesn't look so harmful: why should we avoid using functions like this?

In summary:

- They go against the "philosophy" of modern Fortran.
- There are better ways in modern Fortran to accomplish the same thing.
- They are quite limited.

In every other aspect of Fortran, the attributes of a function result depend only on the arguments of the function and other accessible information.  Here the attributes of the function result may differ with everything else the same through a declaration in an unrelated scope.

To the other points:

- the interface of such a function must be implicit in a referencing place (and we don't like implicit interfaces);
- we can't reference the same function twice in one place and get different length results, even with differing input;
- the function has a much better idea of what length it wants to return.

In those cases where we really do want to control the length in the referencing place we can replace `assumed_len` with a function with explicit length result like

```
function replacement(x, n)
  character(*), intent(in) :: x
  integer, intent(in)      :: n
  character(n)             :: replacement
  ...
end function
```

or a subroutine with assumed length dummy argument

```
subroutine replacement(x, y)
  character(*), intent(in)  :: x
  character(*), intent(out) :: y
  ...
end subroutine
```

Finally, assumed length character functions are declared obsolescent in the current Fortran standard, and may be deleted in later revisions.